# How can I read the text file data and send to telegram bot in python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
import sys
import time
import logging
import requests
import telegram
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler
```

This is read the modified file and print it

```
def on_modified(event_handler):
        print(f'event_handler.src_path={event_handler.src_path}')

    file = open('dataout.txt', 'r')
    f = file.readlines()
    newList = []
    for line in f:
            newList.append(line[:-1])
    print(newList)
```

This is send message to my telegram bot, but I don't know how to link with the text file message

```
def send_msg(text):
    token = "XXXXXX"
    chat_id = "XXXXXX"
   url_req = "https://api.telegram.org/bot"+ token +"/sendMessage" + "?chat_id=" + chat_id + "&text=" + text

    results = requests.get(url_req)
    return results.json()

send_msg("newList")
```

Comment: you should probably remove the question if it is already resolved.

Comment: I google for few days but there have no same thing

Comment: Please rephrase your question and briefly describe your problem with the language used and sample code you tried. Then only people may be able to help you out.

Comment: I posted another question before.... Let me try again

Comment: Should be better now

Answer (score 0):

Well, a third-party library called "telegram" can finish this task

You can install it with the command:

```
pip install python-telegram-bot
```

Then send the message with the API:

```
import telegram

def send_msg(text):
    token = "XXXXXX"
    chat_id = "XXXXXX"
    bot = telegram.Bot(token=token)
    for i in text:
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, text=i)

new_list = []
with open("dataout.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as file:
     new_list = file.read()
for i in new_list:
     send_msg(i)
```

If you have any further problems, feel free to ask me.

Comment: I mean I want to read the text file message then send to telegram. file = open('dataout.txt', 'r') for this I can read it but I can link with telegram send_msg(text):         Thanks for your help!

Comment: Got error: telegram.error.BadRequest: Message must be non-empty

Comment: Now, it sending the letters one by one and not all contents from the text file, only the first contents before the space after that will not send

Comment: I don't know why the print will able show all contents but not send_msg

Comment: Try to use the join method, like send_msg("".join(new_list)

Comment: @WalcottTena Could you please elaborate on the .join method. I am getting one letter at a time too. Thanks